# How to delete a certain range from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([887, 895, 903, 911, 920, 928, 936,  
944, 952, 961, 969, 977, 985, 905, 
914, 924, 934, 944, 954, 965, 975, 986, 996, 1007])
```

The values constantly increase until `985` followed by a drop to `905`. From here on the values start to increase again.

I need a function that detects this drop and deletes all array elements greater than the value it dropped to in such a way that the remaining values are still monotonically increasing (values to be deleted are bold):

[887, 895, 903, **911, 920, 928, 936,

944, 952, 961, 969, 977, 985,** 905, 
914, 924, 934, 944, 954, 965, 975, 986, 996, 1007]

The desired outcome looks as follows:

```
[887, 895, 903, 905, 
914, 924, 934, 944, 954, 965, 975, 986, 996, 1007]
```

How could I do this?

Comment: is there always only one section to delete or can there be several of such drops?

Comment: In your example output, there are values bigger than the one dropped to / from.

Comment: @Cleb there should only be one such section

Comment: @sascha I adjusted the sought output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably more elegant solutions but this seems to work:

```
# get index where you observe the drop
ind_drop = np.where(np.diff(a) < 0)[0] + 1  # or np.argmin(np.diff(a)) + 1

# get index from start of the range which should be deleted
ind_low = np.argmin(a < a[ind_drop])

# delete the requested range
a_new = np.delete(a, np.arange(ind_low, ind_drop, 1))
```

That yields

```
array([  887.,   895.,   903.,   905.,   914.,   924.,   934.,   944.,
         954.,   965.,   975.,   986.,   996.,  1007.])
```

Some explanation:

One has to find the indices at which the array should be cut. The second index, `ind_drop`, is there where we observe the drop i.e. there where the difference between two elements becomes negative for the first time.

```
np.diff(a)
array([  8,   8,   8,   9,   8,   8,   8,   8,   9,   8,   8,   8, -80,
         9,  10,  10,  10,  10,  11,  10,  11,  10,  11])
```

We can get this index by using the a Boolean array

```
np.diff(a) < 0
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

and applying `np.where`.

```
np.where(np.diff(a) < 0)
(array([12]),)
```

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
np.argmin(np.diff(a)) + 1
```

The first index - where we start to cut - we get based on the value corresponding to `ind_drop`

```
a[ind_drop]
array([905])
```

So we need to find the index of the first element which is larger than this value which we can achieve by applying `np.argmin` to a Boolean array:

```
a < a[ind_drop]
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

`np.argmin` returns the (first) index of the minimal value in an array; it works on the Boolean array as `True` is 1, and `False` is 0:

```
np.argmin(a < a[ind_drop])
3
```

Now that we have both indexes, we can use `np.delete` to remove all elements between these indexes:

```
np.arange(ind_low, ind_drop, 1)
array([ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12])
```

yielding the desired output.

Comment: Wow, thats exactly what I needed. Thank you! Now I only need to understand it.

Comment: I don't have much time now, but will add some more explanation later on. I recommend to open an iPython notebook and go through it step by step. But as I said, I will write more explantion later on...

Comment: I got it now. I ran every step in PyCharm debug mode. Explanation maybe would be great for others. Thanks again!

Comment: @M.Weeker: Not sure how many "others" there will be  but I extended the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit robust but should do it:

```
a = [887, 895, 903, 911, 920, 928, 936,  
     944, 952, 961, 969, 977, 985, 905, 
     914, 924, 934, 944, 954, 965, 975,
     986, 996, 1007]

stop = [j for i, j in zip(a, a[1:]) if j < i][0]
drop = False

for i, e in enumerate(a):
    if e > stop:
        drop = i
        break

if drop:
    print(a[:drop] + a[a.index(stop):])

#[887, 895, 903, 905, 914, 924, 934, 944, 954, 965, 975, 986, 996, 1007]
```